# Best way to update an immutable string in dafny

Tags: string, immutability, dafny

I am trying to make verify a program that applies a caeser cipher to a string. The original string must be returned

```
method caesar(s:string, index:int)
//apply caesar
```

What is the best method to update a value of the string, similar to:

```
s[i] := 'x'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to update a string in Dafny. [Strings are represented](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leino/papers/krml243.html#sec-string) as `seq<char>`, and sequences are immutable in Dafny. Immutable means that a sequence is a value and cannot be changed.

If you need to do [in place manipulation](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leino/papers/krml243.html#sec-arrays) you could use an `array<char>` instead.

If you can return a [new sequence](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leino/papers/krml243.html#sec-sequences) you can do

```
var s' := s[i := e];
return s';
```